# Can grep print just the matched buffer?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, perl, grep

If I do

```
# perl -lne "print \$1 if /'?(\d{5})'?:/" courses.yaml
00000
01005
```

then I get the result I want, but now I want to do it with `grep` instead.

Why doesn't the following get me the same output?

```
# grep -oP "\'?(\d{5})\'?:" courses.yaml 
'00000':
'01005':
```

Comment: because it returns everything that gets matched with the regex. You may want to use `\K` or some look-ahead/behind.

Comment: You print Group 1 contents in the first case, and the whole match in the second. Try `grep -oP "(\d{5})(?='?:)" courses.yaml`

Comment: [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13472) provides more detail about the use of lookahead/lookbehind assertions to make `-o` work the way you want it.

Comment: Why not just stick with `perl`? Or better yet, use a `YAML` parser, and don't regex it in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You print Group 1 contents in the first case, and the whole match in the second. When using `grep` with `-oP`, you can only print the whole match, thus, use a `(?='?:)` lookahead that will only return a 5-digit chunk if there is a `:` after them preceded with an optional single quote:

```
echo "'00000':  '01005':" | grep -Po "\d{5}(?='?:)"
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/I1ThGC)

I think there is no point in using a lookbehind here since the `'` is optional in your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`-o` is outputs the match (`$&`), not the first capture (`$1`).

You can use `\K`, look-behinds and/or look-aheads to control what's considered matched.

In your case, you can use the following:

```
grep -oP "'?\K\d{5}(?='?:)" courses.yaml
```

But that simplifies to the following:

```
grep -oP "\d{5}(?='?:)" courses.yaml
```

Using a proper YAML parser would make far more sense, and it would still be quite short.